# Communicate between iPhone and macbook laptop

Tags: ios, http, sockets, networking

In an effort to learn more about networking I'd like to do an exercise: write some code on an iPhone and macbook laptop that allows the devices to communicate over HTTP.

**How would I set this up in general?** I could write a very simple web server as illustrated in [Beej's Guide](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html). Then run this and make requests from the phone. Assume the two devices will be on the same wifi network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using HTTP between two apps is very inefficient. Use NSNetService and raw sockets.

[NSNetService Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNetService_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

There is an example project that shows how to setup the service for publishing, connect 2 services, and consume data from a socket connection.

Answer (score 3):

In this book you can find an example of how to make a network to connect a Mac OS X app with an iOS app using Bonjour.

http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/mobile/9780132757058/bonjour-and-web-servers/ch28

Hope this helps you.